# Dart: stdin.readLineSync

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, user-input

[My problem coding with dart for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liX8s.png)

Please How Can I solve this using VSCODE

I tried standard input but it kept on showing nothing good.

A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.